# cannot load such file -- 2.6/ffi_c && cannot load such file -- ffi_c (LoadError)

Tags: jekyll

I'm a beginner with Jekyll, and I saw there were a lot of questions about this problem but the solution given doesn't fit with my problem, so if someone can help me please? It's been a while I'm on it.

This is the message I get after running `jekyll serve --port`:

```
   Source: /home/a__/repos/Bxgxaxdx.github.io
       Destination: /home/a__/repos/Bxgxaxdx.github.io/_site
 Incremental build: disabled. Enable with --incremental
      Generating... 
                    done in 0.029 seconds.
Traceback (most recent call last):
    32: from /usr/bin/jekyll:11:in `<main>'
    31: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/mercenary.rb:19:in `program'
    30: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/mercenary/program.rb:42:in `go'
    29: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `execute'
    28: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `each'
    27: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `block in execute'
    26: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/jekyll/commands/serve.rb:34:in `block (2 levels) in init_with_program'
    25: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/jekyll/commands/build.rb:39:in `process'
    24: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/jekyll/commands/build.rb:72:in `watch'
    23: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/jekyll/watcher.rb:10:in `watch'
    22: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/listen/listener.rb:91:in `start'
    21: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/listen/fsm.rb:57:in `transition'
    20: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/listen/fsm.rb:91:in `transition_with_callbacks!'
    19: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/listen/fsm.rb:121:in `call'
    18: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/listen/fsm.rb:121:in `instance_eval'
    17: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/listen/listener.rb:68:in `block in <class:Listener>'
    16: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/forwardable.rb:230:in `start'
    15: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/listen/adapter/base.rb:63:in `start'
    14: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/listen/adapter/base.rb:40:in `configure'
    13: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/listen/adapter/base.rb:40:in `each'
    12: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/listen/adapter/base.rb:45:in `block in configure'
    11: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/listen/adapter/linux.rb:30:in `_configure'
    10: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
     9: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
     8: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rb-inotify.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
     7: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
     6: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
     5: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rb-inotify/native.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
     4: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
     3: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
     2: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/ffi.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
     1: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': **cannot load such file -- 2.6/ffi_c (LoadError)**
    33: from /usr/bin/jekyll:11:in `<main>'
    32: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/mercenary.rb:19:in `program'
    31: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/mercenary/program.rb:42:in `go'
    30: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `execute'
    29: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `each'
    28: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `block in execute'
    27: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/jekyll/commands/serve.rb:34:in `block (2 levels) in init_with_program'
    26: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/jekyll/commands/build.rb:39:in `process'
    25: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/jekyll/commands/build.rb:72:in `watch'
    24: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/jekyll/watcher.rb:10:in `watch'
    23: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/listen/listener.rb:91:in `start'
    22: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/listen/fsm.rb:57:in `transition'
    21: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/listen/fsm.rb:91:in `transition_with_callbacks!'
    20: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/listen/fsm.rb:121:in `call'
    19: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/listen/fsm.rb:121:in `instance_eval'
    18: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/listen/listener.rb:68:in `block in <class:Listener>'
    17: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/forwardable.rb:230:in `start'
    16: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/listen/adapter/base.rb:63:in `start'
    15: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/listen/adapter/base.rb:40:in `configure'
    14: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/listen/adapter/base.rb:40:in `each'
    13: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/listen/adapter/base.rb:45:in `block in configure'
    12: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/listen/adapter/linux.rb:30:in `_configure'
    11: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    10: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
     9: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rb-inotify.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
     8: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
     7: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
     6: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rb-inotify/native.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
     5: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
     4: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
     3: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/ffi.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
     2: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/ffi.rb:6:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
     1: from /usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': **cannot load such file -- ffi_c (LoadError)**
```

Comment: this needs formatting from the experts in jekyll

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/65000467/12544391, e.g. adding `gem "ffi"` to `Gemfile` fixed it